# How to run testcafe tests from my MAC in Saucelabs?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I tried to run with the below command in the command line.

```
export NODE_ENV=default | npx testcafe "saucelabs:Chrome@81.0:macOS 10.14" './testCafeTests/userStoryTests/createRoute.js'
```

With my credentials, it is able to connect to sauce, but the browser is not navigating to the URL mentioned in my test.

Can someone please help?

Comment: This information is insufficient to determine the cause of the issue. Can you provide test code and a screenshot of the build page from the Saucelabs Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution of how to run these test . We need to mention the hostname and ports in the command line arguments to run these test in saucelabs.

export NODE_ENV=default | npx testcafe "saucelabs:Chrome@81.0:macOS 10.14" './testCafeTests/userStoryTests/createRoute.js --hostname=localhost --port=8000,8001